# updating gridview rows in asp.net before save it in DB

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

i have made web page for bookstore, in this page i have grid-view reading the book info and QTY from SQL DB then the employee can select the requested rows.
selected Rows  will be copied to generated grid-view then after finishing the order there is save button to send the order to DB.

every thing is done OK till now,
But before saving date in DB employee need to update QTY field for the requested one.
so the update button should change the value, then save it in DB.

any idea about how doing rows update without connecting to DB and before saving the result?

below is part of code:

GridView1 which will read the book info from database:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvAll" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No files found!"  OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging" >


    <Columns><asp:BoundField DataField="ID"   HtmlEncode = "false"/> 
              <asp:BoundField DataField="BookName"   HtmlEncode = "false" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="LangName"  HtmlEncode = "false"/>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="ClassName"  HtmlEncode = "false"/>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Total"   HtmlEncode = "false" />
              <asp:TemplateField>
<HeaderTemplate>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" onclick = "checkAll(this);"
    AutoPostBack = "true"  OnCheckedChanged = "CheckBox_CheckChanged"/>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" onclick = "Check_Click(this)"
   AutoPostBack = "true"  OnCheckedChanged = "CheckBox_CheckChanged" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

GridViews2 which will recieve rows from gridview1:

```
      <asp:GridView ID="gvSelected" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No files found!"  
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Names="Verdana" AllowPaging="True" 
        Width="796px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
        AllowSorting="True" style="text-align: center"  >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55"  BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
        <Columns>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="ID"  > </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BookName" > </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LangID"  > </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ClassID" > </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Total"  > </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Total"  />

        </Columns>
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />

    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="btn_insert" runat="server" onclick="btn_insert_Click" Text="Save Rows" />
```

Now in Cs page i have some code related to make the copy for rows between both Grid as array.

and the btn_insert have connection to database to save result like this:

```
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionStrinrg);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into Table(Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,QTY) values ('" +  g1.Cells[0].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[1].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[2].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[3].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[4].Text + "')", con);
```

the above statment will insert the result from Gridview2 bu3t i want to update field "QTY" before sent it to DB.

Comment: It will be updated once the grid will get the new value from the db

Comment: i want to sent the grid to DB not reading from DB, that's why i want to update the row field before save it in DB

Comment: @FeliceM show some code snippet

Comment: @Firas You can save your in `Session` and then save in db